# Friend member function cannot access private member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intellisense, friend, access-control

I have the following:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    int AFunc(const B& b);
};

class B
{
private:
    int i_;
    friend int A::AFunc(const B&);
};

int A::AFunc(const B& b) { return b.i_; }
```

For the definition of `AFunc` I get that member `B::i_` is inaccessible. What am I doing wrong?

Compiler: MSVC 2013.

**Update**: Changed `AFunc` to public and the code now compiles. However I still get an IntelliSense error. Is this a problem with IntelliSense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you <del>are</del> were declaring another class's `private` function as a `friend`!  `B` should normally have no knowledge of `A`'s private member functions.  G++ 4.9 has the following to say:

```
test.cpp:6:9: error: 'int A::AFunc(const B&)' is private
     int AFunc(const B& b);
         ^
test.cpp:13:33: error: within this context
     friend int A::AFunc(const B&);
                                 ^
```

To solve this, simply declare `B` as a friend of `A`:

```
class A
{
    friend class B;
private:
    int AFunc(const B& b);
};
```

You might be interested in [Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahhw8bzz.aspx).

Comment: The exact quote (if you want to add it) from the C++11 standard is in 11.3/9: *A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration.*

Comment: Thanks! I changed `AFunc` to public (I actually have it public in my real code). Now the code compiles, but I still get an IntelliSense error. Maybe this is a problem with IntellSense? Updated question.

Comment: The code compiles, even in `-pedantic` mode.  I'd say IntelliSense is spewing NonSense.